# Rendered grid on admin tab not working

Tags: magento-1.9, grid-serlization, tabs, admin-panel

I need to show Grid on admin tab of custom module , i have followed this tutorial http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/ , but unable to save old checked value in grid.

1) Layout

```
<company_adminhtml_module_newtabtab>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="company/adminhtml_module_edit_tab_newtab" name="module.tab.newtab"/>
            <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="module_grid_serializer">
               <reference name="module_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>module.tab.newtab</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectednewtab</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[newtab]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>newtab</reload_param_name>
                </action>

               </reference>
            </block>
        </block>
    </company_adminhtml_module_newtabtab>
```

2) Block Newtab.php

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('newtab', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Id'),
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'index'     => 'table_id',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'field_name'=> 'newtab',
            'values'    => $this->_getSelectednewtab(), // values selected properly from database
        ));

        $this->addColumn('table_field_name', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'table_field_name',
            'align'     => 'left',
        ));
    }
```

3) Controller

```
 public function newtabTabAction()
    {


        $test_ids = array(1,2); // your load logic here

       $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('module.tab.newtab')
            ->setNewtab($this->getRequest()->getPost($test_ids, null));


        $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public function newtabGridAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('module.tab.newtab')
            ->setNewtab($this->getRequest()->getPost('newtab', null));

        $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

4) Decoding of serialized id's (showing for newly checked id's)

```
$links=$this->getRequest()->getParam('links', null);

             if ($links['newtab']) {
                 $design_tags = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($links['newtab']);
             }
```